# Using the box api, how can I lock or unlock a file?

Tags: box-api

I would like to build a multi-user app and use box to store the data. I need some sort of concurrency control.

I don't mind making my own simple one, but it seems a basic requirement would be to mark a file as locked or unlocked.  I see only 4 occurrences of the word "lock" in the api documentation, and all of them are related to viewing events, not causing the action.

Is there a concept I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot currently lock or unlock a file with Box's V2 API.

Update: See comments. There is a solution.

Comment: @KurtisLininger Support for locking and unlocking is supposed to be coming this week. Keep an eye on the documentation pages and/or blog.

Comment: @KurtisLininger lock/unlock is not yet documented but is working. You can do a PUT on a file with the request body of... {"lock":{"status":"lock", "expires_at": "2013-12-01T16:51:19-08:00", "is_download_prevented":false}}. To unlock it set the request body to... {"lock":null}

Comment: @paapfly is the above approach still the best way to approach locking and unlocking files?

Comment: @ChadKapatch yes - have you given it a try? http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-update-a-files-information